# How do I set up Jetty 6 & Jboss 4.0.5 virtual hosting?

Tags: jboss, jetty, virtualhost

I have 2 webapps deployed in the same JBoss/Jetty server. In Jetty 5.1.14 I had the following jetty-web.xml which configured one of the apps to run as a virtual host (on the same port):

```
<Configure class="org.jboss.jetty.JBossWebApplicationContext"> 
  <Call name="addVirtualHost"><Arg>app2.localhost.com</Arg></Call> 
</Configure>
```

This worked perfectly fine. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with Jetty 6.1.17 at all. First of all, "JBossWebApplicationContext" seems to now be called "JBossWebAppContext", and secondly the documentation I could find suggests that I should be using a jetty-web.xml that looks like this:

```
<Configure class="org.jboss.jetty.JBossWebAppContext"> 
  <Set name="VirtualHosts"> 
    <Array type="java.lang.String"> 
      <Item>app2.localhost.com</Item> 
    </Array> 
  </Set> 
</Configure>
```

But this doesn't work either. The two webapps deploy without error, but when I try to access the 2nd app under the virtual hostname, it just accesses the first app instead. Both applications are in the root context (this is not negotiable).

How can I make virtual hosts work?

(BTW, I had a friend post this on serverfault a few days ago, but nobody answered.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax works if you include it in the jetty6-web.xml for each web-app.

```
<Configure class="org.jboss.jetty.JBossWebAppContext">
  <Set name="VirtualHosts">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
      <Item>host1.domain.com</Item>
      <Item>host2.domain.com</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

ALL webapps need the virtual hosts defined if they are running in the same container.  For some reason deploying one WAR with virtual hosts and one without doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, we have found that this is either a bug (or a change in features from Jetty 5 to 6) that ALL webapps need to have virtual host(s) defined if one of them does.