# How to configure? Jetty + subdomain + apache

Tags: apache, jetty, subdomain, virtualhost

Friends, I'm trying to configure the following environment:

I have a VPS server, with debian, apache2, jetty 9 and one, just one, webapp.
The url to access my webapp is something like: `http://www.mydomain.net:8080/WebApp`

I want to know if it is possible to get this:

```
http://client1.mydomain.net pointing to http://www.mydomain.net:8080/WebApp
http://client2.mydomain.net pointing to http://www.mydomain.net:8080/WebApp
http://clientN.mydomain.net pointing to http://www.mydomain.net:8080/WebApp
```

Several subdomains (virtual hosts) pointing to only one web app.
It's something like a multi tenant access.

If it's possible can someone please explain me how to do it?
tks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up Jetty 6 & Jboss 4.0.5 virtual hosting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854467/how-do-i-set-up-jetty-6-jboss-4-0-5-virtual-hosting)